# Use class or interface for shared service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to save and pass data through whole application. For That I wrote shared service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface IAccountModel {
  sessionId: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AccountContextService {

  AccountModel: IAccountModel = {
    sessionId: ''
  };

  constructor() { }

}
```

I have question that which one is best practice use class for that or interface to handle data.

What's benefits or disadvantage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces, abstract classes or even classes in place of interfaces, but there is important limitation: only classes and `OpaqueToken`s can be used for injection.

```
class AbstractService {}

class Service extends AbstractService implements IService {}

//will not work
provide: [{provide: IService, useClass: Service}]
constructor(private service:IService){}

//will work
provide: [{provide: AbstractService, useClass: Service}]
constructor(private service:AbstractService){}
constructor(private @Inject(AbstractService) service:IService){}
```